# Android Table Rows Added programatically are invisible

Tags: java, android

the below is the code snippet to dynamically add TableRows

TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyTable);

```
    try
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream ims = assetManager.open("TempData.xml");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(ims);
        XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
         parser.setInput(reader);
         parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT, null, null);

         int eventType = parser.getEventType();

         int count = 0;
         while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String pName = parser.getName();
            switch(eventType) {
               case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                  if(pName.equals("name")) {

              String msg = parser.nextText();
                     //Update the Table with this data
                     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                     tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                     TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                     tv.setText(msg);
                     tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tr.addView(tv);
                     tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     tl.addView(tr);

                //This below code is just to confirm that i am readin the correct data from XML. It is correct btw.
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "data is : " + msg;
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    //Thread.sleep(2);
                  break;
                  }

               default:
                  break;
            } 

            eventType = parser.next();
         }// parse next and gen
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        String ExceptionMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Error is : " + ExceptionMessage;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Can someone tell me why on running this, i do not see any TextViews on the android APP.
There is no exception raised but still blank output.
Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling invalidate() after adding new row.

Comment: Now that's what i call a quick resolution ... u r awesome ... worked like a charm !!!

Comment: Sorry . i got carried away by the result but i have figured out the issue. It was not due to invalidate, but in the above code tv.SetLayoutParams was the one causing the issue. As soon as i removed it, it started working for me without invalidate as well. Not sure how that could be solving the issue but works for me. Can anyone answer how this solved the issue or else i will have to google .. :)

Comment: Can you try this ... LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);  tv.setLayoutParams(params);